# jQuery cannot get input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I am trying to get input value after keypress by jQuery. I have tried few ways to get it and I receive `undefined` or `""`. Using JSF+RichFaces. Input is the `<h:inputTextarea>` Trying to get value by:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         jQuery("#myform:idTextarea").keyup(function(){
            var testValue = jQuery("myform:idTextarea").val();
            console.log(testValue);

        });
     }); 
</script>
```

The variable in log is `undefined`.
When I add "input:" like that

```
var testValue = jQuery("input:myform:idTextarea").val();
```

I get `j_id12`.

When change like that:

```
var testValue = jQuery("#myform:idTextarea").val();
```

I get `""`.

Have someone any clues?

Comment: `#` id referance missing here . `jQuery("myform:idTextarea").val();`

Comment: Can you show your HTML too as the selectors are currently ambiguous?

Comment: Selectors are not ambiguous I have checked that. Html is simple textarea with id. Like `<textearea id="..." class="..." etc.  ></textarea>`

Comment: You are supposed to remove the JSF noise as this is not a JSF/RichFaces problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape CSS meta-character while buidling the jquery selector:

```
jQuery("input\\:myform\\:idTextarea").val();
```

**[Escaping css meta character in jquery](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)**

Comment: That was the problem, but in line when I get component by id - later I used `this` selector. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to find same element for which keyup is registered, just use `this`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         jQuery("#myform:idTextarea").keyup(function(){
            var testValue = jQuery(this).val();
            console.log(testValue);

        });
     }); 
</script>
```